# private members are accessible in angular 2 decorators

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

Consider this code:

```
export class Hero {
    constructor(private id: number, private name: string) {}
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    private title = "Tour of Heroes";
    private hero: Hero = new Hero(1, "Windstorm");
}
```

In `AppComponent`'s template I wrote `hero.name`, however, this field is private according to the `Hero` class and should not be accessible.
How this code compiles and works? am I missing something?

**EDIT:** Read the answers on why it happens, here's my way of handling this, it's not a fix but it keeps things more organized and **safe**, besides accessors are always good to use:

```
export class Hero {
    constructor(private _id: number, private _name: string) { }

    get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }

    get id(): number {
        return this._id;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    private title = "Tour of Heroes";
    private hero: Hero = new Hero(1, "Windstorm");
}
```

When `hero.name` will be executed in JS it should call the JS-compiled getter function you defined in your TS code, this should give some sort of control over the properties while maintaining TS code-style.

Comment: Maybe try `export class Hero { private name: string }` (i.e. not as an argument to the constructor)

Comment: It still compiles, I believe it has something to do with TypeScript transpiler as JS doesn't have private members originally, does it make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript there is no such thing as private variables.  Keywords like `private` are just used by the TypeScript transpiler to enforce constraints before transpilation.  Once the code is transpiled into JavasScript, the `name` property is a visible member of the Hero class.

Comment: Yes I believed this could be the reason, I hoped TS or perhaps angular will check the decorator pre-compilation but it's just a string which angular fills after transpilation I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

The `private` keyword in typescript is just used for compile time checking and doesn't actually restrict access to anything at runtime. The typescript compiler isn't checking your templates so it's not catching the issue.

I believe some IDE's (VS Code and WebStorm) are working on type checking your templates but for now you are on your own

Comment: I am using VS Code, you think there is an extension in the works for type checking templates? I am sure it's possible with VS Code's API

Comment: I believe the Angular 2 team released an API for parsing templates to allow IDEs to do code completing and type checking. Looks like it is already partially supported in WebStorm https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/04/angular-2-workflow-in-webstorm/#ng2-completion
Can't find any official sources on it for VS Code but it's probably only a matter of time before they start supporting it

Comment: that's good to know, btw @rob would you mind to take a look at my edit and let me know if you think `hero.name` in the template will call the JS-compiled `name` getter in my TS script?

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 states referring private variables within templates as a correct way. See cheat-sheet: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-setter.

So go ahead! And enable encapsulation to your components not exposing every variables as public.